# How to stream audio from Nao robot?

Tags: c#, nao-robot

I would like to create a streaming audio from a Nao to my WPF form.

The only way that i have found is that we can download a recorded sound on Nao over SSH.

But its not a real streaming ...

If anyone has an idea !

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

run this command on your NAO (login via ssh) `gst-launch-0.10 pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink port=1234`

list via VLC: `vlc tcp://IP:1234/`

Comment: What should be done for this to work? At least can you point to some manual? Because I get only this response: `ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "pulsesrc"`

Comment: you need a recent system that embed pulsesrc, 1.14 or worst 2.x

Comment: I was running this on NAO version 2.x

Comment: @Alexandre Mazel it does not work on 1.14. I guess, I should try upgrading to 2.0 (or manually recompile kernel with, saying, alsaloop module)

Comment: You can use `alsasrc` instead of `pulsesrc` on older NAOs.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at gstreamer that is embedded in the robot. It would be a bit slow, but it'll be real streaming...

Comment: Did you have any success with it or any manual how to do it?
I tried `gst-launch-0.10 alsasrc`, but got only `Device 'default' is busy`. Pulseaudio is not installed on nao.

Answer (score 0):

For windows:
Download the latest pulseaudio (not the official one) and creat a config.pa file with these two lines:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp listen=0.0.0.0 auth-anonymous=1
load-module module-waveout
```

Run pulseaudio on your windows machine first with pulseaudio -F config.pa

On your NAO:

```
pacmd load-module module-tunnel-sink sink_name=nao server=192.168.1.152
```

(change this address to your windows one. Also make sure pulseaudio is running on windows otherwise this wont work)

```
qicli call ALAudioDevice._listOutputs
```

The previous command will show you the index number of the pulseaudio device you just created. Use this number in the next commands

```
pacmd set-default-sink 1
qicli call ALAudioDevice._setDefaultOutput 1
```

Thats it. Now everything comes through your pc speakers. index 0 is NAO's soundcard

For Linux:
Run this on terminal:

```
pactl load-module module-rtp-recv
```

On NAO:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=nao (creates the sink)
qicli call ALAudioDevice._listOutputs  (checks the index on sink)
qicli call ALAudioDevice._setDefaultOutput 1  
pactl load-module module-rtp-send source=nao.monitor
```

I find the Linux approach more stable. The TCP one on windows might break after some time.